# FirebaseListObservable transforma em Array de Object

Tags: javascript, array, angular, firebase, typescript

Estou usando o Ng2-Smart-Table, segundo a documentação ele aceita uma array de objetos para montar a tabela:

No HTML:

```
 <ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="data"></ng2-smart-table>
```

No Javascript

```
import { NgxDatatableModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';
import { LocalDataSource } from 'ng2-smart-table';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from       'angularfire2/database';
import {forEach} from "@angular/router/src/utils/collection";

@Component({
   selector: 'app-tabela',
   templateUrl: './tabela.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./tabela.component.scss']
)
export class TabelaComponent implements OnInit {

    filTipo: string = 'todos';
    dados: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
    public solicitacoes: Array<Object>;

    constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
        this.dados = this.db.list('/solicitacoes');
        this.dados.forEach(element => {
            this.solicitacoes = element;
        });
        console.log(this.solicitacoes)
      }

      ngOnInit() {
          localStorage.getItem('filTipo');
      }


  }

    // Ng2SmartTable começa aqui



  settings = {
        selectMode: 'multi',
        columns: {
            tipo: {
            title: 'Tipo',
        },
        localizacao: {
            title: 'Localização',
        },
       descricao: {
            title: 'Descrição',
       },
       data: {
            title: 'Data',
      },
   },
   actions: {
     add: false,
     edit: false,
     delete: false,
     open: true,
   }
};

data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Leanne Graham',
    username: 'Bret',
    email: 'Sincere@april.biz',
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Ervin Howell',
    username: 'Antonette',
    email: 'Shanna@melissa.tv',
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Clementine Bauch',
    username: 'Samantha',
    email: 'Nathan@yesenia.net',
  },
  {
    id: 4,
   name: 'Patricia Lebsack',
    username: 'Karianne',
    email: 'Julianne.OConner@kory.org',
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: 'Chelsey Dietrich',
    username: 'Kamren',
    email: 'Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca',
  }
];

// Ng2SmartTable termina aqui

}
```

Estou usando  o `Firebase` para armazenar os dados  e  o `FirebaseListObservable` para buscar as minhas informações, porém não estou conseguindo transformar o `FirebaseListObservable` em uma `array`, tentei colocar a variável solicitacões dentro do `foreach`, porém, quando vou verificar ele me retorna `undefined`.

Tem alguma outra forma de alimentar a minha `smart-table` com um `FirebaseListObservable` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei o problema, o modulo Ng2-Smart-Table necessita da classe LocalDataSource para alimentar a tabela, quando os dados tem origens externas, como o Firebase, ou algum outro service.
Outro problema é que a minha variável solicitação  estava fora do escopo e assim me retornava undefined.
Abaixo o Código atualizado:

```
import { NgxDatatableModule } from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable';
import { LocalDataSource } from 'ng2-smart-table';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { forEach } from "@angular/router/src/utils/collection";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tabela',
  templateUrl: './tabela.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tabela.component.scss']
})
export class TabelaComponent implements OnInit {

  source: LocalDataSource;

  filTipo: string = 'todos';
  dados: FirebaseListObservable;
  public solicitacoes: any;

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.dados = this.db.list('/solicitacoes');
    this.source = new LocalDataSource();
    let _self = this;
    this.dados.forEach(element => {
      _self.source.load(element);
    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {

  }


  settings = {
    selectMode: 'multi',
    columns: {
      tipo: {
        title: 'Tipo',
      },
      endereco: {
        title: 'Localização',
      },
      descSolicitacao: {
        title: 'Descrição',
      },
      data: {
        title: 'Data',
      },
      status: {
        title: 'Status',
      },
    },
    actions: {
      add: false,
      edit: false,
      delete: false,
      open: true,
    }
  };
}
```